# mysqldump data through command line without affecting web application

Tags: database, mysql, mysqladmin

I read some topics on restoring and copying mysql database from 1 server to another

But I wanted to be make sure the impact it might have on my production web app.

So basically here is my situation:

Server A has a database called enrollment.

Server B has a database called enrollment.

Through the command line, how do I do the following:

**1.Create a backup copy of 'enrollment' on Server A**

**2. Drop database enrollment on Server A**

**3. Copy/Dump database enrollmentt from Server B to Server A( do I need to ssh or copy the sql file or can do i do it throug mysql?)**

The databse size is about 64 MB.

While i do the above, how long will the production web app be impacted?

based on my research, this was my thinking, but I wanted to be careful since I am dealing with production data

1. On server B, `mysqldump --databases enrollment > enrollment_backup.sql`
2. scp enrollment_backup.sql from Server B to Server A
3. `drop database enrollment`
4. `mysqldump < enrollment_backup.sql`

Note: I have root access on server A & server B.

Comment: Create an enrollment2 database on both and go for it

Comment: Or let your app run against server B, restore server A, let your app run against server A again.

Comment: Or set up mysql replication and forget this

Comment: thanks. I can't setup replication because between the above because we are migrating data centers. The app cannot read from the new database yet. Until the app is migrated to the new data center, i need to copy new database to the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the **drop database** in the last step:
1) backup server A
2) dump data A on server B
3) change the web app to point to B
4) if everything is ok you can drop server A

Comment: The best approach is to put the web app under maintanence preferently in low traffic hours. 64 mb is pretty small. The dump will be very fast. Then proceed with the approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump any remote server to your local one. Or even any remote server to any other remote server.

```
mysqldump -hproduction -uroot1 -p --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --extended-insert --lock-all-tables --routines --databases mydatabase | \
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot2 -ppassword
```

This will connect to the server `production` with user `root1` and a password you will enter via a prompt. The database `mydatabase` (you can give a list of databases as well) will be dumped.

The standard output with all the commands is then redirected to another MySQL server running on `localhost` (can be any other host as well), using user `root2` and the password `password`. The second password has to be given on the command line.

Advanced possibilities:

- If both systems are not in a VPN or secured by any other means, you can create an SSH tunnel and then dump using this tunnel.
- If you do not want to pass the password via command line or do not want to enter it at all, let `mysqldump` or `mysql` read it from an individual options file via `--defaults-extra-file`.